# GPS Ublox neo-6mv2

Tags: arduino-mega, gps

I'm trying to get gps data from ublox neo-6mv2 module via arduino. Should ublox's neo-6mv2 light blink after power up by 5v from arduino ? Or is there any other sign that tells the module isnt dead ?

Module is connected to 5v, gnd for few hours - still no blink / light.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With respect to your question, your Arduino seems to be serving the purpose of a 5V power source.  It should be more integral to the question.

Comment: Is there any serial (NMEA) output from the GPS? Have you put it outside with a good part of the visible? Is this an original Ublox or a (cheap) clone?

Comment: The Ublox is just the part with the Ublox sticker.  Unless you call out the PCB it is soldered to, we don't have much to go on with respect to LEDs lighting up.

Comment: I have uploaded the picture of my module and code. Yes my arduino mega 2560 is only power supply now. I havent try to get serial output yet - I'm waiting for any sign that the module isnt dead :( It's connected as I said - 5v,gnd, 8 and 9 pin

Comment: You should be able to output the raw NMEA data coming out of the GPS and see if it is “alive”, [see here, for example](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=544053.0). The cheap/generic GPS modules I know only start blinking an LED after they’ve acquired an initial position, which can take a *very* long time.

Comment: [added photo]
I have found a post that on arduino mega is better to use Serial(1/2/3) than SoftwareSerial so I tried it. Now it shows some data so I assume it's alive even without any light blinking on the module. Thanks everyone :)
All the data are the same - it's waiting for the signal right ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the active antenna is attached and may have to move it around to differnent areas of you work bench. some of these modules are very deaf or prone to inteference from reflections in the room.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).